# compute the gradient (dy/dx) in tensorflow with the same size of y

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I want to calculate the gradient of dy/dx and get the gradient in size
of y plus the dimensions of x to indicate diffrentiation wrt variable in x.
for example if Y[100x1]=A[100x50]X[50x1] so return Y[100x1x50x1].
(for each parameter in x give me the diffrentiation of Y)

I've tried the tf.gradients operator:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients

However, it returns the sum(dy/dx) instead of dy/dx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not actually want to calculate a gradient, you want to calculate the Jacobian. A gradient is the application of the nabla operator to a scalar function with respect to a vector while the Jacobian is simply a matrix where every element J_ij is the derivative of y_i with respect to x_j, which is what you want.

This is still not implemented in Tensorflow, but has been discussed in detail [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675). You'll probably find a working way for you there.

The basic Idea is to call the [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) with respect to only one variable at a time and then constructing the Jacobian from there manually.